# Three.js 360 Image - Texture marked for update but image is incomplete

Tags: javascript, three.js

This is the code I'm using -

```
var camera, scene, renderer;
        var Container = document.getElementById('container');
        var imageFile = Container.getAttribute('data');

        var isUserInteracting = false,
        onMouseDownMouseX = 0, onMouseDownMouseY = 0,
        lon = 0, onMouseDownLon = 0,
        lat = 0, onMouseDownLat = 0,
        phi = 0, theta = 0;

        init();
        animate();



        function closeModal() {

        }


        function init() {

            var container, mesh;

            container = document.getElementById( 'gallery-modal' );

            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1100 );
            camera.target = new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, 0 );

            scene = new THREE.Scene();

            var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 500, 60, 40 );
            geometry.scale( - 1, 1, 1 );

            var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {
                map: new THREE.TextureLoader().load(  imageFile )
            } );

            mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );

            scene.add( mesh );

            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
            renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
            //renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, 500);
            container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );


            // Controls to move the image
            document.addEventListener( 'mousedown', onDocumentMouseDown, false );
            document.addEventListener( 'mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false );
            document.addEventListener( 'mouseup', onDocumentMouseUp, false );
            document.addEventListener( 'wheel', onDocumentMouseWheel, false );

            document.addEventListener( 'dragover', function ( event ) {

                event.preventDefault();
                event.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'copy';

            }, false );

            document.addEventListener( 'dragenter', function ( event ) {

                document.body.style.opacity = 0.5;

            }, false );

            document.addEventListener( 'dragleave', function ( event ) {

                document.body.style.opacity = 1;

            }, false );

            var galleryDOM = document.getElementById('gallery');
            var modal = document.getElementById('gallery-modal');

                galleryDOM.addEventListener('click', function(e) {

                    if(e.target.localName == 'img') {

                        //console.log(e.target.src);

                        modal.style.display = "block";

                        var reader = new FileReader();

                        reader.addEventListener('load', function(e) {

                           material.map.image.src = e.target.result;
                           material.map.needsUpdate = true;

                        }, false);

                    }
                });

                window.onclick = function(event) {
                    if (event.target == modal) {
                        modal.style.display = 'none';
                    }
                }


            window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

        }

        function onWindowResize() {

            camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
            camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

        }

        function onDocumentMouseDown( event ) {

            event.preventDefault();

            isUserInteracting = true;

            onPointerDownPointerX = event.clientX;
            onPointerDownPointerY = event.clientY;

            onPointerDownLon = lon;
            onPointerDownLat = lat;

        }

        function onDocumentMouseMove( event ) {

            if ( isUserInteracting === true ) {

                lon = ( onPointerDownPointerX - event.clientX ) * 0.1 + onPointerDownLon;
                lat = ( event.clientY - onPointerDownPointerY ) * 0.1 + onPointerDownLat;

            }

        }

        function onDocumentMouseUp( event ) {

            isUserInteracting = false;

        }

        function onDocumentMouseWheel( event ) {

            camera.fov += event.deltaY * 0.05;
            camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

        }

        function animate() {

            requestAnimationFrame( animate );
            update();

        }

        function update() {

            if ( isUserInteracting === false ) {

                lon += 0.1;

            }

            lat = Math.max( - 85, Math.min( 85, lat ) );
            phi = THREE.Math.degToRad( 90 - lat );
            theta = THREE.Math.degToRad( lon );

            camera.target.x = 500 * Math.sin( phi ) * Math.cos( theta );
            camera.target.y = 500 * Math.cos( phi );
            camera.target.z = 500 * Math.sin( phi ) * Math.sin( theta );

            camera.lookAt( camera.target );

            /*
            // distortion
            camera.position.copy( camera.target ).negate();
            */

            renderer.render( scene, camera );

        }
```

UPDATE** I'm no longer recieving an error, but this also isn't changing the texture image?

I've add my entire code. I'm trying to create a gallery effect, click a placeholder image, modal opens with 360 image, but I need to it switch 360 images based on the placeholder clicked.

Comment: I may have figured it out - I think passing the URL of the img is incorrect and I need to use the FileReader() api.

Comment: Great you solved it yourself! Could you add an answer with code example of your change for future visitors? Thanks in advance!

Comment: No error, but this doesn't change the texture image.

Comment: Why don't you use [THREE.TextureLoader](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/loaders/TextureLoader)?

Comment: @Mugen87 I am, I just added the entirety of my code.

Comment: What is the reason for using `FileReader`? Besides, it seems you just add an event listener but not reading in any data.

Comment: @Mugen87 I'm referencing this function - `document.addEventListener( 'drop', function ( event ) {

     event.preventDefault();

     var reader = new FileReader();

     reader.addEventListener( 'load', function ( event ) {

      material.map.image.src = event.target.result;
      material.map.needsUpdate = true;

     }, false );
     reader.readAsDataURL( event.dataTransfer.files[ 0 ] );

     document.body.style.opacity = 1;

    }, false );
`